# Programmatically add UITableView to custom MKAnnotation using Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So, I have created a custom `MKAnnotation` and a custom callout that gets shown, when the annotation is tapped. I am trying to add a `UITableView` to the callout, but its `frame` is always 0. This is code step by step:

This is the custom callout class and its `init` method.

```
class QuestGiverAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    init(frame: CGRect, giver: NonPlayableCharacter) {
        self.questGiver = giver

        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.commonInit()
        self.applyStyles()
        self.applyConstraints()
    }
}
```

This is how I initialize the `UITableView` (in `commonInit()`):

```
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .Plain)
    self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.rightContainer.addSubview(self.tableView)
    self.addSubviews([self.rightContainer, self.leftContainer, self.separator])
```

These are the constraints I've set:

```
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-20-[rightContainer]-20-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[rightContainer]-20-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))

    self.rightContainer.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.rightContainer.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

And these are the delegate methods (only placeholders for testing puropses):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("hest", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "quest"
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)

    return cell
}
```

The problem with all of this is, that the table has a frame of 0, but if I set the `width` and `height` to some constants in the constraints, it correctly shows the two cells. Also, I have a few more views in the callout and they all show correctly, so the problem is in the table.

**EDIT:**
Here are the other constraints for the callout:

```
    let views = [
        "avatar" : avatar,
        "nameLabel" : nameLabel,
        "separator" : separator,
        "leftContainer" : leftContainer,
        "rightContainer" : rightContainer,
        "tableView" : tableView,
    ]

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.leftContainer, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[leftContainer]-10-[separator(1)]-5-[rightContainer]-5-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[leftContainer]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[separator]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[rightContainer]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))

    self.leftContainer.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[avatar(30)]-5-[nameLabel]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.leftContainer.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[avatar(30)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.leftContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.avatar, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.leftContainer, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.leftContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nameLabel, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.avatar, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    self.rightContainer.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.rightContainer.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

And the complete `commonInit` implementation:

```
    self.avatar = UIImageView.autoLayout()
    self.nameLabel = UILabel.autoLayout()
    self.separator = UIView.autoLayout()

    self.rightContainer = UIView.autoLayout()
    self.leftContainer = UIView.autoLayout()
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .Grouped)
    self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.leftContainer.addSubviews([self.avatar, self.nameLabel])
    self.rightContainer.addSubview(self.tableView)
    self.addSubviews([self.rightContainer, self.leftContainer, self.separator])
```

Comment: I suspect the annotation size is computed from the sizes of its subviews, so you need to specify the width and height of your tableView.  You already said that works, which tells me that the annotation size isn't fixed or you would be over constrained at that point. I would think that you'd want the table to be a specific size so why not just specify it?

Comment: Yep, the annotation size is also computed using Autolayout, but I don't want the table view to have a fixed size, I want it to stretch to the whole height of the callout. The problem is, that the other views in the callout are computed dynamically, so I can't know what the size of the callout will be.

Comment: Could you show the code for the other views in your callout.  Right now it looks like you have a tableView that completely fills rightContainer, and rightContainer is 20 points away from the sides of the callout.  Where is there room for anything else?

Comment: You said you want the table to stretch to the height of the callout.  You still will have to specify the width.

Comment: Ok, I want the whole callout to stretch, so that the table's contents fit entirely. Lets say I have 4 rows, I want the table to show all 4 rows and stretch its width, so that the text in the cells is visible. I've updated the answer with the other constraints I've used.

Comment: I don't believe there is an automatic way to do that.  You will need to explicitly set a width and height for rightContainer after computing how tall to make it to show the number of rows you want to be visible at this time.  If the table can grow while you are viewing it, keep a reference to the height constraint and update its constant when rows are added or removed from the tableView.

Comment: You might be able to use the `.contentSize` property that `tableView` inherits from `UIScrollView` to find the height of your content.